# How to design large Database, Entity–relationship model

Tags: database, postgresql, erd

I normally design databases entity–relationship model with Visio and then the relationship model. But now I have to design a DB with a lot of entities and relationsship.

Which end up looking very confusing in Visio, so my question is, are there any programms which allow displaying large db models easly or are there any design models for large dbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this post: http://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/top-6-data-modeling-tools

Usually, you don't have to visualize the whole Entities and Relationships in a single diagram. You partition your entities into smaller concepts/modules, etc. The repository (of a tool that you use, I believe including visio) would have all the entities you defined, and a selected set of them are visualized in a diagram